# How to get specific values from Redis INFO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Following documentation from, https://redis.io/commands/info

I want to get specific key/values from returned `bulk string`

For example:

```
# Rails Controller Code
redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)
render json: redis.INFO

... returns ....

# Server
redis_version:999.999.999
redis_git_sha1:3c968ff0
redis_git_dirty:0
......
......

# Memory
used_memory:167560008
used_memory_human:159.80M
used_memory_rss:174358528
used_memory_rss_human:166.28M
.....
```

I want to only get **used_memory** and so on.

Is it possible  without using Ruby tweaks?

**ALSO** how can I use `MEMORY DOCTOR` to get information, given I have initialized the Redis in my controller? (e.g `redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)`)

https://redis.io/commands/memory-doctor

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to get relevant key-value pairs

```
redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)
redis.info #=> returns hash
result = redis.info.slice('used_memory_human', 'used_memory_rss')
#=>  {"used_memory_human"=>"1.10M", "used_memory_rss"=>"700416"}
render json: result
```

Comment: Thanks it works :)
one more thing, any idea regarding my 2nd Q about Memory Doctor?

Comment: Or percentage of total memory used?